# Transcoding and streaming live 1080 http streams

Tags: streaming

I would like to ask how we can transcode live http stream with Raspberry Pi by using gpu?

Transcoding SD and HD live streams from 1080i to 720p for example, and stream this outside network

Thx in advance

ps: We can use ffmpeg or vlc?

Comment: Using GPU, maybe one stream at a time using gstreamer-omx implementation. But really, you need a proper server and software to be a master at this, not a puny Pi.

Comment: Hm, If Pi can transcode one HD channel, believe me this is what I need..Anyway, can you be so kind I give me more info on how exactly to implement this gstreamer+omx?

Comment: If you are asking how to do this (e.g. with x264 and/or ffmpeg), it's not really a pi specific question.  Whether the hardware is used properly is up to the software -- about which you may or may not have any choice.

Comment: You are on the wrong page. Its about gstreamer-omx. Please if you do not have idea, do not post. Thx in advance

Comment: I have managed to transcode 1 SD channel with RPI gstreamer 1.0  –omx via Hardware.
Not sure how to do HD channel or example 2 SD channels on one RPI, which will be best 

CPU 70%, no so good quality picture ,also audio out of sync

Can you help me out with a proper pipe to reduce cpu? 

sudo gst-launch-1.0 uridecodebin uri="http://192.168.0.102:35000" use-buffering=true name=d \
{d. ! videoconvert ! omxh264enc target-bitrate=1500000 control-rate=variable ! mux.} \
{d. ! audioconvert ! voaacenc ! mux.} \
mpegtsmux name=mux ! tcpserversink host=192.168.0.104 port=5000 sync=true

Comment: Anyone to help out? Need proper pipe line to transcode live http incoming channels with gstreamer-omx